# How do I turn off the new Facebook photo album browser?

Tags: facebook, photos

When I'm using facebook on my mac to browse my friend's photo albums, it pops up with this new browser.  It's a font window, black background, arrows to go forward or backward and you can press escape to get out of it.  You can still see the rest of the album behind it.  In the old one, it would take you to a new page when you browsed individual photos.  I still get this old style browser when using facebook on my linux machine.

I wouldn't really have a problem with using the new one, except that it still seems pretty buggy.  Often I am not able to comment on albums or photos on my mac that I can comment on from the old browser on my linux machine.  Is there any way to turn it off?  I can't find any settings of this nature for the life of me.

Answer (score 1):

just press F5 or refresh your page whenever the new lightbox pops up, alternatively remove the

> &theater

from url in the address bar and go